# VBA AutoFilter gives runtime error 1004

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Could anybody help me find what's wrong in the autofilter line below?
It gives run time error '1004'.

```
Sub filter()
    Dim rng_source As Range
    Set rng_source = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    rng_source.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that there is nothing within or "near" cell **A1** in the active sheet.